# Unable to create Cassandra node running on m3.* instance type using OpsCenter

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

We installed DSE cluster (4.0.3) on EC2 using the [instructions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMIlaunch.html) published by Datastax.

We decided to launch [ami-ada2b6c4](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?region=us-east-1#launchAmi=ami-ada2b6c4) on the m3.large instance types and everything ran as expected.

However, we tried to add an additional Cassandra node through OpsCenter (Nodes->Add Node -> Add Cassandra Node) and we are unable to select any m3 instance type.

Any help is appreciated.

Best,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of instance types that are built-in to OpsCenter are the ones they tested with at the time of the OpsCenter release. Amazon releases new instance types and those are not automatically available, but usually picked up in future OpsCenter releases.

There are two possible workarounds for getting the instance type/size you want, and still managing it through OpsCenter:

1. Launch new bare EC2 instances through the AWS console, then install Java on each. In OpsCenter choose Create Brand New Cluster, then choose the Local tab. You'll give the private IP addresses for each node and OpsCenter will install Cassandra/DataStax.
2. Launch new EC2 instances using the DataStax AMI and create your Cassandra cluster manually. Then once it's up and running go to OpsCenter and choose the Manage Existing Cluster option.

Option #2 is probably more manual work. You can see more details in the [OpsCenter](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.1/opsc/online_help/opscCreatingCluster_t.html) and [Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/install_cassandraTOC.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks BrianC. And where in the UI would I be able to select an existing instance?

Comment: @tmueller I expanded the answer to cover a bit more of that. The online docs do a pretty good job of explaining the different ways of installing everything.

Comment: @tmueller we just pushed an update to existing releases of OpsCenter to represent the latest ec2 instance sizes, so you can either wait an hour or so for OpsCenter to automatically pick that up or you can restart the opscenterd process.